# Neural network cost function oscillating with number of epochs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I'm implementing a 4-5-3 neural network for the iris dataset with sigmoid activation and a cross entropy loss function. But the graph of the loss vs the number of epochs is oscillating and I have no idea why. Any help will be appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zguAw.jpg

Comment: Do you train by batch or the whole epoch at the time? Is your data sequentially put into training data or sampled randomly?

Comment: The whole epoch and I picked random examples from my training set, 120 random examples to be exact

Comment: Your learning rate is too high.

Comment: my learning rate is 10^-5, and going lower didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you normalize the data? I got an oscillating loss curve on another problem and that helped.